# How do I query and obtain data from CloudKit?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I am fairly new to Swift, and just started learning about CloudKit this week for an iOS app project.

The database is working, I can add records and find records in the database.

I have run into a problem sending a query to CloudKit and accessing the data related to the query.

The CloudKit data has unique identifiers, so the search is for one of those identifiers (so a query should only return one record). I am then trying to obtain three pieces of information from that record - "UPC", "foodName", and "Ingredients"  (all strings)

Here is the code section that executes the query and tries to obtain the data.

```
let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "UPC = %@", subStr)

let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Food", predicate: predicate)

publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil,
                    completionHandler: ({results, error in

       if (error != nil) {
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                     print("CloudKit Error")
                            }
                        } else {
        if results!.count > 0 {

            var record = results as! CKRecord

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            print("UPC Found")
            let cloudUPC = record.objectForKey("UPC") as! CKAsset
            print("UPC from CloudKit \(cloudUPC)")

                }
            } else {
               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                    print("UPC Not Found")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }))
```

The crash occurs at this point

```
 var record = results as! CKRecord
```

and returns "EXC_Breakpoint(code = 1, subcode - 0x10047b7c)

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: `results` is an array of `CKRecord`. You can't simply cast the array to `CKRecord`. Loop through the array.

Comment: @rmaddy That should be an answer and not a comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestion rmaddy.

This is how I fixed the code

```
let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "UPC = %@", subStr)

let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Food", predicate: predicate)

publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil,
                completionHandler: ({results, error in

                    if (error != nil) {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            print("Cloud Error")
                        }
                    } else {
                        if results!.count > 0 {


          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {


         for entry in results! {
         let cloudUPC = entry["UPC"] as? String
         print("UPC from CloudKit \(cloudUPC)")

         let cloudFoodName = entry["foodName"] as? String
         print("Name from CloudKit \(cloudFoodName)")

         let cloudIngredients = entry["Ingredients"] as? String
         print("Ingredients from CloudKit \(cloudIngredients)")

          }
        } else {
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                print("UPC Not Found")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to first to write for loop on items in record then print each UPC 
like that :

```
for item in record {
print(item["UPC"]
print(item["foodName"]
}
```